# How I use confirm using sweet alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sweetalert

I want replace standart confirm dialog. 
My javascript function is here

```
function checkDelete() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning", showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes Delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function () {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
}
```

How i use sweet alert confirm function in gridview templatefield button?

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="60" HeaderText="Delete">     
    <ItemTemplate>        
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeleteUser" Runat="server" OnClientClick="checkDelete();" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>     
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Standart confirm function is here

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="60" HeaderText="Delete">     
     <ItemTemplate>        
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeleteUser" Runat="server" OnClientClick=" return confirm('Are you sure?');" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>     
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Standart confirm function is runnning. But sweet alert confirm function is not running. Please help

This is standart confirm

[image]

Plase help.

Comment: It is impossible to have a custom alert/confirm and have it return a value since there is no "wait" in JavaScript. You would have to cancel the click action and than trigger the click/submit from the JavaScript code.

Comment: i use http://alertifyjs.com/ was working all the time

Comment: how can i do with sweetalert? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, It will help you

```
  swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file.",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#F44336",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, Sure !",
            closeOnConfirm: true
        }, function () {

                        swal({
                            title: "Message",
                            text: 'Imaginary file deleted.',
                            type: "success"
                        });    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how is your issue going so far, but here is my ugly solution.

```
        function confirmBeforePostback(obj) {
            var res = $(obj).attr('onclick').split(';');

            if (res.length > 1) {
                swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "The will delete your record, are you sure?",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        closeOnConfirm: true,
                        closeOnCancel: true
                    },
                    function (isConfirm) {
                        if (isConfirm) {
                            eval(res[1]);
                        }
                    });
            }
            return false;
        }
```

And in the asp.net, add code to the onclick attribute like below example.

Code behind:

```
((Button)e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[2]).Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirmBeforePostback(this)) return false;";
```

or ASPX:

```
<ItemTemplate>        
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeleteUser" Runat="server" OnClientClick="confirmBeforePostback(this);" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>     
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs help in the future here is the piece of code i have used to implement this.

```
 swal({
            title: '',
            text: "Are you sure you want to delete selected record(s) ?",
            type: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            cancelButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> @Resources.No',
            confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> @Resources.Yes'
        }).then(function () {
            //  loop on selected rows and remove them using jquery datatable method.

            //  display sweet alert
            swal(
        {
            title: "",
            text: "Record Deleted",
            type: "success",
            allowOutsideClick: "true"
        });

        })
```

Happy coding!